# Feature extraction process using too much memory and causing a crash. What can I do?

Tags: python, deep-learning, memory-leaks, huggingface-transformers

[image]I am using a hugging face transformer to do some image feature extraction to use later for some similarity search functionality. This is not working currently because after processing around 200 images too much memory is being used and crashes the system... what am I doing wrong? what can I change to fix this.
Here is my feature extraction class:

```
import numpy as np
from transformers import AutoProcessor, AutoModelForZeroShotImageClassification, AutoTokenizer, TFCLIPModel


def expand_greyscale_image_channels(grey_pil_image):
    grey_image_arr = np.array(grey_pil_image)
    grey_image_arr = np.expand_dims(grey_image_arr, -1)
    grey_image_arr_3_channel = grey_image_arr.repeat(3, axis=-1)
    return grey_image_arr_3_channel

def get_color_image(img):
    img = img.resize((224, 224))
    img = img.convert('RGB')
    return img

def get_greyscale_image(img):
    img = img.resize((224, 224))
    img = img.convert('L')
    img = expand_greyscale_image_channels(img)
    return img

class FeatureExtractor:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        pass
    
    def __init__(self, processor=None, model=None, tokenizer=None, text_model=None):

        self.processor = processor
        self.model = model
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.text_model = text_model

    def model(self):
        return self.model
    
    def processor(self):
        return self.processor
    
    def extract_features(self, img, grey=False):
        """
        Extract a deep feature from an input image
        Args:
            img: from PIL.Image.open(path) or tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(path)

        Returns:
            feature (np.ndarray): deep feature with the shape=(4096, )
        """
        try:
            if grey:
                img = get_greyscale_image(img)
            else:
                img = get_color_image(img)
            inputs = self.processor(images=img, return_tensors="pt")
            image_features = self.model.get_image_features(**inputs)
            # Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.
            image_features /= image_features.norm(dim=-1, keepdim=True)
            return image_features.detach().numpy()  # Normalize
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        
    def extract_text_features(self, text):
        try:
            inputs = self.tokenizer([text], padding=True, return_tensors="tf")
            text_features = self.text_model.get_text_features(**inputs)
            text_features = text_features / np.linalg.norm(text_features)
            return text_features.numpy()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Here is the function that I run in a loop over each image url:

```
fe = FeatureExtractor(processor, model, tokenizer, text_model)
def get_features_for_image(image_meta):
    id = image_meta["id"]
    image_url = image_meta["image_url"]
    # get features for image
    try:
        # open image from url
        image = get_pil_image_from_url(image_url)
        # resize image
        image = image.resize((224, 224))
        # if file not in features folder
        # extract features
        if not os.path.exists("features/" + id + ".npy"):
            # with FeatureExtractor(processor, model, tokenizer, text_model) as fe:
            image_features = fe.extract_features(image)
            np.save("features/" + id + ".npy", image_features)
            del image_features
            del image
            gc.collect()
            
            # write features to the json file

            # save featuers under file features/id.npy

        return True

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error extracting features for image ", id, " error: ", e)
```

where is the memory leak? how can I fix it?

Here is the image of cpu usage. It is doing fine per image, as the number of images that features are extracted for in total increases so does the cpu usage. even if the model uses a lot of memory, shouldn't it recover the memory after the feature of each image is done extracting?

Comment: please show a plot of system memory usage over time that spans sufficient time to _demonstrate_ a steady leak. if this cannot be demonstrated, the issue isn't a leak but merely the AI requiring lots of memory in general.

Comment: Another thing to note is that memory fragmentation can sometimes look like a leak, but isn't. Diagnosing memory problems is not always straight-forward, and requires a bit of knowledge about how the operating system's memory management works.

Comment: I added the image, at the bottom are my thoughts on the issue, I have done this before  when I have all the images downloaded to a folder, this issue started happening when I am trying to iterate over urls instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Its the line image_features.detach.numpy() in extract_features
the detach() creates a separate copy of the numpy array. It is not needed here and created the leak.